# Is it possible to not show a picture after it's taken on iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want a user to take a picture, but I don't want to display the picture after it's taken to the user. I want to hide the photo and take the user to a different screen after it's taken.

Is this possible with React-Native?

Comment: The logic to handle wether to display or not solely depends on you. By default RN component returns the image object.

Comment: So I can override that default behavior then? Is there a specific SDK for RN camera interaction that you'd recommend?

Comment: What RN component are you using to take pictures?

Comment: I was looking at react-native-camera, but I know that it probably differs between SDK's.